# What do the symbols for these binary operations on a set mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binary-operations

If *S* = {0,1,2,3,4} and *(a,b)* is an arbitrary ordered pair such that *a ∈ S* and *b ∈ S*, which of the matchings in Exercises 12-15 are binary operations on *S*? Construct operation tables.

12. *(a,b)* ----> *a * b* = *2a - b*
13. *(a,b)* ----> *a ∇ b* is the maximum of *a* and *b*
14. *(a,b)* ----> *a Δ b* = either *a* or *b*
15. *(a,b)* ----> *a ∬ b* = 2

Background: I'm on the introductory Review section of my dad's old "Algebra and Trigonometry" textbook from 1971 (authors: Kane, Oesterle, Bechtel, Finco) and everything described is great, but these symbols looked like they popped up out of nowhere.  Can anyone explain what they are and how they are being used?  Are they related to a branch of mathematics that is more advanced than algebra?

Comment: The symbols are red herrings. You can use any symbol you want to represent anything, just like you could use a smiley face and mad face instead of $a$ and $b$ in your definitions.

Comment: The book is introducing the symbols and defining them by the given expressions. The point is to check whether the operations defined in that way are valid **binary operations on $S$**. The book should have explained what it means to be a binary operation on a set.

Comment: They explain in detail all about sets and binary operations on the set.  So the symbols can be anything and what the description says after each symbol is how that symbol is being used?  I'm still a little confused as to how they are using them.  Would you be able to give the ordered pairs for number 12?  I'm going at this on my own - I don't have any resources besides here and my intuition lol.  Much appreciate it.

Comment: For instance, $1*3 = -1$ since $1*3$ means $2\cdot 1 - 3$ where here $\cdot$ and $-$ represents the usual multiplication and subtraction taught to small children

Comment: The punchline you should be aware of here is that if you perform a binary operation using elements of the set you should sure hope to get back a specific result and should hope for that result to also be in $S$.  If it breaks either of those rules, we can't call it that.  You've seen binary operations all your life, you just haven't known to call them that... like addition of natural numbers, or division of nonzero rational numbers, etc...  You can also see plenty of examples in real life that are not binary operations like talking about what "dog times cat" should equal

Comment: Ahh I see now, that clarifies it a lot more.  Appreciate the detailed response, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the book writes "$a \nabla b$ is the maximum of $a$ and $b$", that is a more concise way of writing "Define $\nabla$ as follows: for every $a,b$, $a \nabla b$ is the maximum of $a$ and $b$".  Then, the book is asking you to determine whether the map $(a,b) \mapsto a \nabla b$ is a binary operation on $S$.

In other words, $\nabla$ is not an existing symbol that already has an accepted meaning.  Rather, the book is defining a new symbol (just for the purposes of the exercise), and then asking you a question about it.

I suggest you review the definition of "binary operation on $S$" carefully.  The book is asking you to understand the abstract definition by applying it to some concrete examples.  See if you can think of an example of a set $S$ and an operator that is *not* a binary operation on $S$.

Comment: Let's say a = 0, b = 2, how does the maximum relate to a binary operation?  Are they implying that, 0+2 = 2 which is the maximum of (0,2) and + is the binary operation?

Comment: What do you understand a binary operation to be?

Comment: @ConMan So far, an operation involving addition, subtraction, multiplication and division on two operands.  I don't understand how the question is worded (regarding the maximum of two numbers) in relation to a binary operation.  The way I read it, the maximum of (0,2) is 2 ... great, but how is that a binary operation?  It's just comparison, is how I see it.  Unless that's the point of the question.  Possibly a case of overthinking on my end, but definitely would like clarification.

Comment: @AnthonyBaldini, see my edited answer and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4871620/what-do-the-symbols-for-these-binary-operations-on-a-set-mean/4871670?noredirect=1#comment10386382_4871620.  This site isn't designed for interactive feedback or back-and-forth interaction, so you might need to seek a tutor or spend some more time working through this on your own and see if you're able to formulate a new question.

Comment: @AnthonyBaldini Like D.W. says, this isn't the place for back-and-forth, so I'll just suggest you look up what binary operations are in general.